# testing tools for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, mobile

What are the free testing tools for android and iOS mobile application?

Answer (score 3):

For Android, [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) is a hot one!

Comment: Robotium is really a very nice testing framework. Pure simplicity in comparison to Apple' UIAutomation, which sucks big time.

Answer (score 2):

Seetest is a one more testing tool. You can download its trial version. Why I suggest this to use over robotium is because of its platform independence. Just write a test script for android and run the same script across all the other platforms like Windows Phone, IPhone, Blackberry, Symbian.
Here is the link to download its trial version.
http://experitest.com/support/download-2/

Thanks,
Sangram

Answer (score 1):

Android has the [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html).

Answer (score 1):

What about Robotium? http://code.google.com/p/robotium/
Or MoneyTalk (was FoneMonkey) - http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/fonemonkey